# Will + the verb 'marry'

Tags: verbs

Are the following sentences correct?

> Will I marry in five years?
> No, you won't marry in five years.

It feels like there's something missing between the verb 'marry' and the following words. Is a person missing after 'will' and 'marry'?

For example,

> Will I marry Anna in five years?

Is it more correct to say,

> I will be married in five years.

or

> I will get married in five years.

Answer (score 3):

When "to marry" is used with no object it is a rather formal verb. When an object is used "to marry"  is  current.

[will I marry](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22will%20i%20marry%22&tbm=bks&lr=lang_en)

[will I get married](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22will%20i%20get%20married%22&tbm=bks&lr=lang_en)

When there is no object, the more usual verbal expression is "to get married".

> Will I marry in five years?
> No, you won't marry in five years.

- Will I get  married in five years?
  No, you won't get married in five years.

> I will be married in five years.
>
> I will get married in five years.

Both are correct but you are not saying the same thing. In the first sentence you are only asking whether in the coming five years the event of your marriage will occur, whereas in the second you are asking whether you are going to get married when five years have gone by.

Comment: Not sure how you can type "mill" instead of "will", are you using some kind of handwriting recognition, or just mixing up "marry" and "will"?

Comment: @StuartF M and W are far apart on my keyboard, so I can figure out how that happened.

Answer (score 1):

Your first two examples are correct. ***Marry*** is not always a transitive verb, and so it does not always need an object:

> **intransitive** verb
> to take a spouse : WED
>
> - He first ***married*** at twenty. ([M-W](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/marry))

Comment: To clarify: it's nothing to do with "will". Your argument, @Anna, is based on the wrong assumption that _marry_ has to be transitive. It is most often transitive, and I suspect even more often in recent English; but intransitive _marry_, though a little old-fashioned, is still found.

Comment: @ColinFine -  When I was younger, people said 'He _never married_.' about a certain kind of man.

Comment: I think there is another point at issue here. If one says simply "Will I marry in five years?" it could mean "in the next five years", but it could also mean "in the five years starting from the point that some other thing is going to happen" eg. If my medical training begins in 2026 and lasts five years - will I marry during that time?  As it is written - without the word "next"- the sentence lacks clarity concerning which five-year period is meant.